# SQL project in visual studio getting failed

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, sqlproj

SQL project in visual studio getting failed.
with below error.

SQL72003: The value 160 for property CompatibilityMode was not valid.

Don't have any idea about it. Could anyone from community guide me to fix this one.
Thanks

Comment: 160 CompatibilityMode equates to SQL Server 2022 - are you trying to deploy a project to an older version of SQL?

Comment: Thanks @AnthonyNorwood for reply. I am just trying to build the project. 
Afterwards I found out that one of the developer has edited the proj file and added <CompatibilityMode>160</CompatibilityMode> in it. I have modified it to 150 and it worked for me.